# cert-manager.io/v1 Certificate no acme field

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cert-manager, google-cloud-dns, acme

I am trying to migrate `cert-manager` to API v1, I was able to migrate the Issuer to ClusterIssue (the first part of the YAML). However, I am dealing with a breaking change that there is no more `acme` on kind Certificate

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-myapp-issuer
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: ssl@company.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: wildcard-myapp-com
    solvers:
      - dns01:
          cloudDNS:
            serviceAccountSecretRef:
              name: clouddns-service-account
              key: key.json
            project: project-id

---

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: myapp-com-tls
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: myapp-com-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-myapp-issuer
  commonName: '*.myapp.com'
  dnsNames:
  - myapp.com
  acme:
    config:
    - dns01:
        provider: google-dns
      domains:
      - '*.myapp.com'
      - myapp.com
```

When I run kubectl apply I got the error:

> error validating data: ValidationError(Certificate.spec): unknown field "acme" in io.cert-manager.v1.Certificate.spec

How can I migrate to the new version of cert-manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of v0.8, a new format for configure ACME Certificate resources has been introduced. Notably, challenge solver configuration has moved from the Certificate resource (under `certificate.spec.acme`) and now resides on your configure Issuer resource, under `issuer.spec.acme.solvers`.

So the result manifests should be as following;

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-myapp-issuer
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: ssl@company.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: wildcard-myapp-com
    solvers:
      - selector:
          dnsNames:
          - '*.myapp.com'
          - myapp.com
        dns01:
          cloudDNS:
            serviceAccountSecretRef:
              name: clouddns-service-account
              key: key.json
            project: project-id

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: myapp-com-tls
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: myapp-com-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-myapp-issuer
  commonName: '*.myapp.com'
  dnsNames:
  - myapp.com
```